# Everything synced by iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud, security, privacy

I want to know each and every core files my Mac sync with iCloud even the hidden files which one normally can't edit.

I want to know what are other things iCloud sync except the items that are listed in the iCloud settings like:

- iCloud Drive
- Photos
- Mail
- Calendar
- Contacts
- Reminders
- Notes
- Keychain
- Safari (reading lists, iCloud tabs)

What does Apple sync with iCloud we don't know about?

Comment: Sorry - I don’t really understand. Are you saying you want to sync EVERYTHING on your computer, including system, application, and library files?

Comment: Nope I am asking what are the things iCloud sync except the few option I see in the system preference of iCloud I know iCloud syncs safari reminders notes etc but I want to know is there anything else which iCloud syncs

Comment: what have you included in etc as from "...iCloud tabs etc" ?

Comment: iCloud drive,photos,mail,contacts,calenders,reminders,safari,noteskeychain so my question is except these few things what else does iCloud syncs with my mac?

Comment: I still don't know - what are the things (every small element) iCloud syncs/backups!